# Cloud run (serving) errors blocked by browser because of missing access-control-allow-origin header

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

We're running an Angular application and a REST API on Cloud Run instances, deployed using Terraform.

Sometimes the api instance gets overwhelmed with requests, and GCP (not the REST API) returns `429` errors. These errors don't include any CORS headers, the browser blocks them because of the missing `ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN` header, and Angular doesn't receive the responses with correct HTTP code.

The result is that users of the Angular application get a console error, while we have dedicated built-in error handling in the application. For example, if the REST API returns `429` errors the application will retry the request at a later moment.

Our error handling generally works well, but as I said it only works when the API returns these errors, not when the errors originates in GCP itself.

I tried to find a setting for cloud run that would allow the user to set cors headers for GCP errors, but I couldn't find any. Moreover, I looked for the origin of the error, but could only find [a page](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting) detailing how to troubleshoot the errors.

---

The HTTP responses in question have this payload:

```
The request was aborted because there was no available instance. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#abort-request
```

At the time of the errors, Google Cloud is creating more instances (going from 1 active run instance to 5 active run instances), because of a surge of requests. In the logs and metrics it looks like the instance receives approximately 58 requests in a second. 14 requests don't make it to the instance itself and receive the error in question. Logging shows a request latency of 0ms, which seems to indicate that Google Cloud doesn't wait for the new instances to be booted up.

---

Our cloud infrastructure is configured as follows:

- Cloud run instances

  - `api` API (NestJS)

    - Container settings, copied from the revision overview
      | Container settings    | |
      | --------------------- | -------------- |
      | CPU allocation        | CPU is only allocated during request processing |
      | Startup CPU boost     | Disabled |
      | Concurrency           | 80 |
      | Request timeout       | 120 seconds |
      | Execution environment | First generation (default) |
      | Min instances         | 1 |
      | Max instances         | 5 |
  - `web-app` Front-end web-app (Angular)
- Serverless regional network endpoint groups (all of type 'Cloud Run')

  - `api-neg` API

    - Connected to service `api`
  - `web-app-neg` Front-end web-app

    - Connected to service `web-app`
- Load balancer

  - Backends (Classic application load balancer (EXTERNAL))

    - `load-balancer-backend-api` API

      - Connected to `api-neg`
    - `load-balancer-backend-web-app`

      - Connected to `web-app-neg`
  - UrlMap

    - `api.example.com`: `/` and `/*` connected to `load-balancer-backend-api`
    - `app.example.com`: `/` and `/*` connected to `load-balancer-backend-web-app`
    - All unmatched requests are connected to `load-balancer-backend-web-app`

Comment: Did you figure out why Cloud Run trigger 429 sometimes?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the client was saving a lot of data at the same time, which triggered a lot of concurrent requests. The API should be able to rate-limit the requests, but before it can GCP intercepts the requests. I'm not sure why, since the limit of concurrent requests for the cloud run instance is twice as high as the amount of requests shown in the metrics.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP status 429 is being returned by the GFE (Google Frontend). I am not aware of a method to add CORS headers at the GFE.

You should be using a Cloud Run custom domain mapping so that your client is not making a cross-origin request. Another option is to use a load balancer with a domain.

You will still have the HTTP status 429 problem which should also be solved but at least your client will know about the issue instead of being masked by CORS.

Comment: Ah, I was afraid that it wouldn't be possible to add CORS headers to the front-end...

At the moment the api is already (only) accessible through an external load balancer. This load balancer also serves as a reverse proxy, using urls such as `api.example.com` and `app.example.com` for our api and Angular front-end respectively.

I don't really understand what the outcome would be when using a custom domain mapping; wouldn't that still result in responses from `api.example.com` being blocked in the browser, if the browser application is at `app.example.com`?

Comment: @tlepel - your question does not mention a load balancer or a custom domain mapping configured on the load balancer. Details like that are important. Edit your question and show exactly what you have configured and exactly how the calls are made. Provided that you are using your configured domain mapping, then you should not have a CORS error. Based on your comment, the 429 is not coming from the GFE, but instead from your load balancer and that indicates another set of problems.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasn't clear about that before, the original question now includes an overview of the infrastructure we use. Are there any other details that could impact the behaviour of the GFE/Load balancer regarding the 429 errors?

Comment: @tlepel - The error is `The request was aborted because there was no available instance.`. What settings did you use when you deployed Cloud Run? Are you researching these error messages?

Comment: I added the cloud run container settings to the question. I was researching the error messages, and added a short overview of my findings as well. Basically, Google Cloud is booting up more instances to spread the amount of requests, but even before the maximum amount of concurrent requests is reached the 429 errors are thrown. There are no logs indicating the root cause of the 429 errors, I'd expected the first instance to still accept requests until 80 requests were being processed.